# topLayoutGuide.length depreciated

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, deprecated, safearealayoutguide

I am still a beginner with xCode and would be happy if someone could help me. This is my code:

```
if(magnetLinkTextField.frame.origin.y<=0) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.magnetLinkTextField.frame = CGRect(x: self.magnetLinkTextField.frame.origin.x,
                                                        y: self.topLayoutGuide.length,
                                                        width: self.magnetLinkTextField.frame.size.width,
                                                        height: self.magnetLinkTextField.frame.size.height)
            }
        }
```

How can I implement the following:

> 'topLayoutGuide' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use
>   view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of
>   topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor

Comment: You should correct your tags

Comment: in your view builder: look for constraint top, select it and change the elem to safeArea

Comment: put a screen of the view builder select the magnetLinkTextField. Though I'm not sure what you're trying to acheive. is that an error or just a warning in the console

Comment: we should to StackOverflow to slove your problem, first you must provide enough infos to helps us help you

Comment: do you have it on github ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create this programmatically example for you with autolayout and animation copy and paste in a new project to see it:
first declare your textfield and the button (to activate animation) under ViewController class

```
let yourTextfield = UITextField()
let button = UIButton()
```

after that declare constraints var to use for animation:

```
var goToTop: NSLayoutConstraint?
var stayHere: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

now in viewDidLoad construct the textfield and the button, assign an action to a button, present them and add constraint:

```
view.backgroundColor = .red
    
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.setTitle("put on top", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleGo), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    yourTextfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Your textfield", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)])
    yourTextfield.textColor = .black
    yourTextfield.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    yourTextfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(yourTextfield)
    yourTextfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    yourTextfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    yourTextfield.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stayHere = yourTextfield.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    stayHere?.isActive = true
    goToTop = yourTextfield.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

now write the function for animation:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleGo() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.stayHere?.isActive = false
        self.goToTop?.isActive = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

this is the result, adapt it to your project... Hope this help :)

Comment: No, I haven't a Github... Tell me what do you want to do and I help you.

Comment: Search for marucca on Github

Comment: Hi @Boostvolt, yes I see it but it's too complicated for me ... I don't think that with my knowledge can help you, I'm sorry ...